# How to prevent my rails app to give away available emails once a user has requested to reset his password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want my rails app, which i use devise gem, not to give away the availability of an email in my database when a user requests to reset his/her password, after he/she has forgotten it while trying to login.

Please if possible you can also provide the link of the reference material for me to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that you don't want the app to say that an account with that email address was found in your database in case this is used as a way to find account names to try and break into.  If so, then devise has a paranoid setting which will mean that the messages for password reset, resend confirmation etc. are vague and say that an email will have been sent if that email address exists in the database, without actually saying if it does or not.  (It doesn't do this for registerable because if someone tried to create an account with a duplicate email address, devise thinks they should be told the creation failed.)  The line you need in your `devise.rb` initialiser is:

```
config.paranoid = true
```

It's probably already there, just commented out with a comment above explaining it.

Here's a link to the blog post announcing this feature:

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/11/e-mail-enumeration-in-devise-in-paranoid-mode/